# How can I list files modified within a directory yesterday via command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, date

I'd like to list out all files with modification dates in the last *n* days (or even simply *after* Y-m-d) in a directory.  It must work recursively through all subdirectories as well.

How can I do this?

Ideal output:

```
file.txt    Mar  26 15:15
file2.txt    Mar  27 01:15
```

Acceptable output:

```
file.txt
file2.txt
```

**Answered!** (Thanks for all the help)

```
$ find . -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -lah {} \;
-rw-r--rw- 1 apache apache 18K Mar 26 08:22 ./file1.txt
-rw-r--rw- 1 apache apache 12K Mar 26 09:23 ./dir1/file2.txt
-rw-r--rw- 1 apache apache 16K Mar 26 10:24 ./dir1/dir2/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find . -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} \;`

will list all files within last 24 hours, with a long listing just to confirm modification date

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
find . -mtime +1
```

For more informations, see

```
man find
```

Comment: Below command lists all files in current directory (.) which modification time is older than 1 day. Give the output you want to have in original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
find dir -mtime +1 -print
```

That will find all files in dir and subdirectories that were modified 1 day ago or before that.

Comment: Thanks, I need this after n days, not before.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant! This searches for files at least 1 day old! In any case, you can use -mtime -1 to achieve the opposite result.